# How to organize API response data into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, request

I am new to python and I have been struggling with organizing the API data into pandas. I am currently using a list to setup the columns but... every time I try to do a sub part of the schema it throws back a list error. here is what I have so far.

```py
itemlist = []

for item in response['items']:

    required = {
        'status' : item['status'],
        'start_date' :item['start_date'],
        'date_created' : item['created_at'],
        'Job Category' : item['category'],
        'revenue' : item['payments_deposits_total'],
        'techs_assigned' : item['techs_assigned']
    }

    itemlist.append(required)
```

The issue is that the object **tech assigned** is made up by 3 different areas. Id, first_name, and last_name. I can't figure out how to include those in the dictionary. Every time I try to add it to the object I get a list error.

Here is an example of the response:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "integer",
      "number": "string",
      "check_number": "string",
      "priority": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "tech_notes": "string",
      "completion_notes": "string",
      "payment_status": "string",
      "taxes_fees_total": "number",
      "drive_labor_total": "number",
      "billable_expenses_total": "number",
      "total": "number",
      "payments_deposits_total": "number",
      "due_total": "number",
      "cost_total": "number",
      "duration": "integer",
      "time_frame_promised_start": "string",
      "time_frame_promised_end": "string",
      "start_date": "datetime",
      "end_date": "datetime",
      "created_at": "datetime",
      "updated_at": "datetime",
      "closed_at": "datetime",
      "customer_id": "integer",
      "customer_name": "string",
      "parent_customer": "string",
      "status": "string",
      "sub_status": "string",
      "contact_first_name": "string",
      "contact_last_name": "string",
      "street_1": "string",
      "street_2": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state_prov": "string",
      "postal_code": "string",
      "location_name": "string",
      "is_gated": "boolean",
      "gate_instructions": "string",
      "category": "string",
      "source": "string",
      "payment_type": "string",
      "customer_payment_terms": "string",
      "project": "string",
      "phase": "string",
      "po_number": "string",
      "contract": "string",
      "note_to_customer": "string",
      "called_in_by": "string",
      "is_requires_follow_up": "boolean",
      "agents": [
        {
          "id": "integer",
          "first_name": "string",
          "last_name": "string"
        }
      ],
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": "any",
          "type": "string",
          "group": "string",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "is_required": "boolean"
        }
      ],
      "pictures": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "file_location": "string",
          "doc_type": "string",
          "comment": "string",
          "sort": "integer",
          "is_private": "boolean",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "customer_doc_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "documents": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "file_location": "string",
          "doc_type": "string",
          "comment": "string",
          "sort": "integer",
          "is_private": "boolean",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "customer_doc_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "equipment": [
        {
          "id": "integer",
          "type": "string",
          "make": "string",
          "model": "string",
          "sku": "string",
          "serial_number": "string",
          "location": "string",
          "notes": "string",
          "extended_warranty_provider": "string",
          "is_extended_warranty": "boolean",
          "extended_warranty_date": "datetime",
          "warranty_date": "datetime",
          "install_date": "datetime",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "customer_id": "integer",
          "customer": "string",
          "customer_location": "string",
          "custom_fields": [
            {
              "name": "string",
              "value": "any",
              "type": "string",
              "group": "string",
              "created_at": "datetime",
              "updated_at": "datetime",
              "is_required": "boolean"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "techs_assigned": [
        {
          "id": "integer",
          "first_name": "string",
          "last_name": "string"
        }
      ],
      "tasks": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "start_time": "string",
          "start_date": "datetime",
          "end_date": "datetime",
          "is_completed": "boolean",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime"
        }
      ],
      "notes": [
        {
          "notes": "string",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime"
        }
      ],
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "multiplier": "integer",
          "rate": "number",
          "total": "number",
          "cost": "number",
          "actual_cost": "number",
          "item_index": "integer",
          "parent_index": "integer",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "is_show_rate_items": "boolean",
          "tax": "string",
          "product": "string",
          "product_list_id": "integer",
          "warehouse_id": "integer",
          "pattern_row_id": "integer",
          "qbo_class_id": "integer",
          "qbd_class_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "services": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "multiplier": "integer",
          "rate": "number",
          "total": "number",
          "cost": "number",
          "actual_cost": "number",
          "item_index": "integer",
          "parent_index": "integer",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "is_show_rate_items": "boolean",
          "tax": "string",
          "service": "string",
          "service_list_id": "integer",
          "service_rate_id": "integer",
          "pattern_row_id": "integer",
          "qbo_class_id": "integer",
          "qbd_class_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "other_charges": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "rate": "number",
          "total": "number",
          "charge_index": "integer",
          "parent_index": "integer",
          "is_percentage": "boolean",
          "is_discount": "boolean",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "other_charge": "string",
          "applies_to": "string",
          "service_list_id": "integer",
          "other_charge_id": "integer",
          "pattern_row_id": "integer",
          "qbo_class_id": "integer",
          "qbd_class_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "labor_charges": [
        {
          "drive_time": "integer",
          "drive_time_rate": "number",
          "drive_time_cost": "number",
          "drive_time_start": "string",
          "drive_time_end": "string",
          "is_drive_time_billed": "boolean",
          "labor_time": "integer",
          "labor_time_rate": "number",
          "labor_time_cost": "number",
          "labor_time_start": "string",
          "labor_time_end": "string",
          "labor_date": "datetime",
          "is_labor_time_billed": "boolean",
          "total": "number",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "is_status_generated": "boolean",
          "user": "string",
          "visit_id": "integer",
          "qbo_class_id": "integer",
          "qbd_class_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "expenses": [
        {
          "purchased_from": "string",
          "notes": "string",
          "amount": "number",
          "is_billable": "boolean",
          "date": "datetime",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "user": "string",
          "category": "string",
          "qbo_class_id": "integer",
          "qbd_class_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "payments": [
        {
          "transaction_type": "string",
          "transaction_token": "string",
          "transaction_id": "string",
          "payment_transaction_id": "integer",
          "original_transaction_id": "integer",
          "apply_to": "string",
          "amount": "number",
          "memo": "string",
          "authorization_code": "string",
          "bill_to_street_address": "string",
          "bill_to_postal_code": "string",
          "bill_to_country": "string",
          "reference_number": "string",
          "is_resync_qbo": "boolean",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "received_on": "datetime",
          "qbo_synced_date": "datetime",
          "qbo_id": "integer",
          "qbd_id": "string",
          "customer": "string",
          "type": "string",
          "invoice_id": "integer",
          "gateway_id": "integer",
          "receipt_id": "string"
        }
      ],
      "invoices": [
        {
          "id": "integer",
          "number": "integer",
          "currency": "string",
          "po_number": "string",
          "terms": "string",
          "customer_message": "string",
          "notes": "string",
          "pay_online_url": "string",
          "qbo_invoice_no": "integer",
          "qbo_sync_token": "integer",
          "qbo_synced_date": "datetime",
          "qbo_id": "integer",
          "qbd_id": "string",
          "total": "number",
          "is_paid": "boolean",
          "date": "datetime",
          "mail_send_date": "datetime",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime",
          "customer": "string",
          "customer_contact": "string",
          "payment_terms": "string",
          "bill_to_customer_id": "integer",
          "bill_to_customer_location_id": "integer",
          "bill_to_customer_contact_id": "integer",
          "bill_to_email_id": "integer",
          "bill_to_phone_id": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "signatures": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "file_name": "string",
          "created_at": "datetime",
          "updated_at": "datetime"
        }
      ],
      "printable_work_order": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "url": "string"
        }
      ],
      "visits": [
        {
          "notes_for_techs": "string",
          "time_frame_promised_start": "string",
          "time_frame_promised_end": "string",
          "duration": "integer",
          "is_text_notified": "boolean",
          "is_voice_notified": "boolean",
          "start_date": "datetime",
          "status": "string",
          "techs_assigned": [
            {
              "id": "integer",
              "first_name": "string",
              "last_name": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_expandable": [
    "string"
  ],
  "_meta": {
    "totalCount": "integer",
    "pageCount": "integer",
    "currentPage": "integer",
    "perPage": "integer"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Going to make an assumption here seeing as you haven't shown us example data.

Sounds like you've got a nested dictionary? You will just need to stack the keys. Eg: item[tech_assigned][id] to get the id

Comment: I get a type error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    'Techs' : item['techs_assigned']['first_name'],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

this comes when I try to stack the keys.
'Techs' : item['techs_assigned']['first_name'],

Comment: Okay so you don't have a pure dict in techs_assigned. It's a list of ducts I guess? If it is you'll need to decide on if you are okay with using a list comprehension to get those values as a list.

Comment: Hmmm, so how do I get those values as a list?

Comment: If you can edit your question to show an example of your data I'll be able to help more

Comment: I updated the question. I don't understand how you know when things are pure dicts or when they are ducts. Because when I look at the json sample data it all looks the same.

Comment: So if you have a dict inside a list [ ] that's when you have a list of dicts. So in the example data you gave you would need to use 'Techs' : item['techs_assigned'][0]['first_name']. If there could be more than 1 tech assigned then you want a list comprehension such as: 'Techs' : [tech['first_name'] for tech in item['techs_assigned']]

Comment: Thank you. List comprehension saved the day. I will remember that!

Comment: One more question,
for the visits category. There is a category below that one that says techs assigned. how do i pull that with list comprehension?

Comment: should be something like  [tech['first_name'] for tech in item['visits']['techs_assigned'][0]]

Comment: I am getting a type error

'''   'Add. Visit Techs' : [tech['first_name']for tech in item['visits']['techs_assigned'][0]],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? If you are not comfortable with accessing dict values I recommend you try and learn that aspect first otherwise you will struggle

Comment: I have tried googling and I have finished some classes in python dictionaries. I understand that there is the list in the json. I just don't understand how to access the list below the main values. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There are a lot of different cases so I can't go over all of them. I think your question should use:  [tech['first_name'] for tech in item['visits'][0]['techs_assigned'][0]]